# SSH Tunnel Connection keeps dropping

Tags: ssh, port, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am developing a site whereby the site connects to a clients server to query the database. A ssh tunnel was created and this approach has worked fine for all sites but one. I'm assuming that because this is specific to one clients server it would be on their end but cannot figure out what the issue is.

I have tried a variety of different ways to locate the problem and the closest I have come is to locate what i believe are references to the error in auth.log. The following line appears with some regularity;

```
error: channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen on port: 24011
```

We originally had the tunnel set up for 24001 so its not a port specific problem. Where should i go from here in trying to rectify this problem? Thanks in advance for any help provided.

I have also noticed that there are multiple instances of plink.exe running on the server. Might this be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't have some process (possibly a duplicate execution?) already listening to that specific port on the respective server.

Comment: I noticed there are mutliple instances of plink.exe and ping.exe running on the host server. I changed the port and ended the processes but the same thing has happened again. Any suggestions as to why there would be multiple plink instances and how i can ensure this doesnt happen if it is the cause.

Comment: Duplicate host entries in some config file (copy-paste error)? How do your sites know how to contact each other?